# Google sheets beginners question to average unit price formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am doing a test for a data analytics bootcamp. i have to use google sheets and i am an absolute beginner.
We have a dataset called products that we have to extract on a google spreadsheet first. I will upload the link to my google spreadsheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m67VmLZispyTwFTmPdppsdJNtbvnZsZK2LBCSchUWmU/edit?usp=sharing

the question is to use a formula to say what the average unit price of all products listed is.

My formula was to write under colum F(unit price) the formula: =AVERAGE(F2:F78). but the number i get is 44702 which cant be correct, if you look at the table.
also i dont know if i have to consider Column E, where the quantityperunit is stated to answer the question.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: where does this data come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like I answered this for you in another post recently. But I can add more details.

You are working with a spreadsheet that seems to have been created in the United States, yet you've set the locale to Germany. This is creating a conflict, because the decimal separator in Germany is a comma while the decimal separator in the US is a period.

In addition, your Col-F values are all strings, not numbers — except for the one entry in F66. So you have mixed data types, and math functions can't act on that mix.

This leaves the only valid number being `21.05`. However, as I said, in Germany, this is *not* a valid number. It's a *date*: May 21. And the data of May 21 (2022) is 44702 days since the Google Sheets origin date of December 30, 1899 (which is how Sheets stores all dates). So that is why you are getting that result.

If you change your locale to "United States," this will solve *some* of your issues. But no matter what your locale, it won't change those strings in Col F to real numbers. So you'll need to convert them in place, or your formula is going to need to account for them.

Seeing as this is an assignment, it's unclear whether the instructor intended for you to have to address these problems, or whether the additional problems are an unintentional result of spreadsheet conversions that happened somewhere.

In addition to all of that, you interpreted the original question in your post rather than sharing the actual exact wording of the question; and wording matters.

First, I would ask the instructor if the numbers in Col F were all supposed to be real numbers, or if most of them being strings is part of the assignment.

In any case, given exactly what you have right now, this should produce the *average unit price* (regardless of quantity in stock, as we don't know the actual wording of that question):

`=ArrayFormula(ROUND(AVERAGE(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(F2:F78&"",".",","))),2))`

It's a lot longer than it would have needed to be if not for the multiple factors I described above. That is, given the locale setting of Germany and the fact that you have mixed data types, *all* of the Col-F values had to be converted to strings, then all of the periods had to be `SUBSTITUTE`d with commas, then they *all* had to be converted to numbers with `VALUE` before `AVERAGE` could be applied.

Comment: thanks!! will have to read it a few times to fully understand it haha. mhhhh.. i think there has to be an error when converting the data onto google spreadsheet. because the data i put into google spreadsheet i converted from a data stack a german company gave me, so it seems really weird you identified the data begin from the states.  and also , because it is supposed to be a beginners test, i dont think it should be that complicated to solve hahah. will try to change my locale on my leptop. also: the original phrase of the question is: what is the average unit price of all products listed?

Comment: Are you saying that the instructor did not provide the same data to all people taking the course? In what format was the original data, and how did you get it into Google Sheets (e.g., manually, copy/paste, one of the IMPORT functions, other)?

Comment: Did the solution I provided work and answer your question as posted? Please take a moment to mark the post as "Best Answer." This will effectively close the post. In addition, I see that you are continuing to post asking for new help. It's a small community here. If the volunteers see that you don't adequately respond when someone puts in time helping you, you're likely to find your additional posts poorly received or passed over.

Comment: Hey, Tyler! i am veray new to this and work on the side. so i did not have the time to properly run the program with your solution. as soon as i do, i will get back to you! the format of the original data was in a zip folder. it is a very unorganized excel table. we had to extract that to  google sheets. our results we have to present them on a new google sheets table.

Comment: I understand that you "work on the side"; but most people who donate time here *also* work (e.g., I work full time). I mean this to be helpful advice: if you have enough time to post new questions, then you have enough time to check on and reply to those who offer help on your previous posts. Otherwise, it seems as though you are just bombarding the forum with work and expecting the volunteers to continue to do that work for you. My suggestion: post *one* issue and follow that through to the end before posting your next issue, etc.

Comment: You also seem to be in a hurry to get through these problems, which makes it seem like these spreadsheet questions are for a job requirement (i.e., proof that you have certain skills in order to advance to a new job position) rather than just being for a voluntary course. Maybe that is not true. But it *seems* that way. And that may cause many volunteers here to feel conflicted about helping you, if it seems that you may be somehow "cheating on a test" (i.e. having other people "do the test for you"). I encourage you to be clear about this in your future posts, if that is not the case.